# Check LocalStorage Constantly

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to check the client localstorage at all times with angularjs? The reason I want to do this is because I have set a JSON Web Token in the local storage when the user logs in. Furthermore, I am using

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {});
```

to check the token. Once it is found to have expired, the user is logged out. However, with this method, the user has to make an API request in order for the check to be reinitialized. Is there a way to observe the token that is stored inside of the localStorage and as soon as it expires, then log the user out without the need for an API request?

Comment: You could add an http interceptor (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). So, as soon as the user try to make any API request with an expired token, it will be logged out.

Comment: It's possible to do that, but there is no an easy way. Also you should notice that when you have such a use case most probably is because a security issue, and in that case you should consider using sessions on the server side. Because the **localstorage ** can be modified in the browser with no restrictions.

Comment: Try using the $scope.$watch() / $localStorage combo - $scope.$watch() essentially allows you to set up any kind of expression for dirty checking, and $localStorage intergates with the angular mechanics - which means it should trigger a digest anytime a change occurs in there

Comment: @IAmDranged I tried that, but the problem is that the token does not actually change when it expires. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I already do have this in place. What I am trying to achieve is logging the user WITHOUT a request being made. Instead, logging them out when the JSON web token in the localstorage expires.

Comment: @ David - Sure, I missed some of that. Why not arranging for $setInterval to fire every second to check current time vs the expiration time?

Comment: @IAmDranged Thank you. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use @IAMDranged 's suggestion:

```
       setInterval(function() {

            var token = $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
            self.parseJwt = function(token) {
                var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
                var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
                return JSON.parse($window.atob(base64));
            }
            var expireTime = self.parseJwt(token);
            var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
            var timeCheck = expireTime.exp - timeStamp;


            //Set to expire after 15 seconds
            if (timeCheck < 86385) {
                console.log('time expired');
            } else {
                console.log('time not expired');
            }


        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create/get the token you don't know after how much time it will be expires? because if you know you can save the expiration time/date in the `localStorage` and when the page is loaded or the token changed (the user login or logout) use `setTimeout` to logout the user when the token should be expired.

If you don't know the expiration time (what i think is the case) the best think you can do is to send the token to the server on every request and make the server check the token on every request (consider using `cookie` instead of `localStorage`), if the token is ok let the server do the work, otherwise make the server return `403 http error` and in the client side use `$httpInterceptor` to check if the server return status `403` and logout the user (instead of doing request to check the token on every state change).

**Edit:** Add Code example (for the first solution). You should call this function when the token changed too.

```
angular.module('...')
    .run(['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        var _timeout;
        function deleteTokenTimeout() {
            if (_timeout) {
                _timeout.cancel();
            }
            _timeout = $timeout(function () {
                // remove the token
            }, new Date(localStorage.getItem('expiration')) - new Date());
        }

        deleteTokenTimeout();
    }]);
```

Comment: Leibale Eidelman, I am manually setting the JSON Web Token with my chosen expiration time. I tried setTimeout but the problem is that if the user refreshes the page, timeout is then reset.

Comment: "... **when the page is loaded** ..."
i edit the answare and added code example